# Fetching HTML information after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, discord, fetch, jsdom

So basically I'm trying to make a discord bot to fetch the player data within a game called Venge.io. Their api is private and requires a token to access.

I tried using the code below to fetch the overall page of my specific stats:

```
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}test`)){
        JSDOM.fromURL("https://social.venge.io/#Izzi").then(dom => {
            console.log(dom.serialize());
        });
    }
```

The outcome resulting in things such as this:

```
<li>
   <span class="label">KILLS</span>
   <span class="value">{{details.kills}}</span>
</li>
```

*(Snippet of the long amount of html)*

When inspecting it loaded manually, it gives a result such as this:

```
<li>
   <span class="label">KILLS</span>
   <span class="value">11748</span>
</li>
```

I'm looking to figure out how I can fetch the loaded html instead of the raw html so I can then use this for multiple users and more things available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just checked the site you mentioned and it's a Vue.js SPA. You can't use JSDOM for parsing dynamic web pages; you will need a headless browser, like [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/), which can execute JS functions.

If you open the page, you can see the Vue application (a global `app` variable). In your browser's console you can access `app.details` and see that it contains all the data you may need, including `details.kills`.

So you can spin up a headless browser and grab the variables you need, without touching the DOM. Check out the snippet below, it should work fine:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getUserDetails(username) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const url = `https://social.venge.io/#${username}`;

  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

  const handle = await page.evaluateHandle(() => app.details);
  const details = await handle.jsonValue();

  await browser.close();

  return details;
}

getUserDetails('Izzi')
  .then((details) => console.log(details.kills));
```

Comment: That worked, I wasn't even aware of puppeteer, and this gets the job done. Thanks for this, going to read up more on puppeteer to also learn about it more!